# PostgreSQL- Common table expression update column from SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have this code which intents to generate a hash password for all values of a column in a table.

The issue comes when I see the results, only one hash is created (repeated for the number of rows of the table), instead of one different per row/value in column cust_cif.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

ALTER TABLE pec4.tb_customer
ADD password VARCHAR (255);

WITH password_new AS (
    SELECT cust_cif, crypt('cust_cif', gen_salt('md5')) AS pass
FROM pec4.tb_customer
)

UPDATE tb_customer 
SET password = p.pass
FROM password_new p;
```

If I execute the query (only the select part), I get the output I want (one hash per row/value):

```
SELECT cust_cif, crypt('cust_cif', gen_salt('md5')) AS pass
FROM pec4.tb_customer
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use this update: `update tb_customer set password=crypt(cust_cif, gen_salt('md5'));` ?

Comment: Hi @Luuk. If I do that I get the output from the image? Let me try

Comment: It just a simple way to write the UPDATE.  I (also) have no clue why your statement is producing the same result for all rows, or it must be the single quotes around `cust_cif`.

Comment: `update tb_customer set password=crypt(cust_cif, gen_salt('md5'));` should be OK.

Comment: Your query using the CTE gets a single value since the CTE itself in executed only once. The initial reason (at least one of them) was this very thing, you could get a result then use it multiple times times, and be guaranteed the same values. Prior to CTEs you had to repeat the statement/clause for each use. If you want different values do not use a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

After the update you could (or should?) check if the password hash is OK.

You can do that using this statement, which should return `t` in the last column:

```
select t.*, (password=crypt(cust_cif,password)) from tb_customer t;
```

Your statement will only return `t` when you do:

```
select t.*, (password=crypt('cust_cif',password)) from tb_customer t;
```

which is checking if the password is `'cust_cif'`, and not if the password is the value stored in the field `cust_cif`.

Your statement is missing the link between tb_customer and the password_new table. Corrected to work your statement should be:

```
WITH password_new AS (
    SELECT cust_cif, crypt(cust_cif, gen_salt('md5')) AS pass
FROM tb_customer
)
UPDATE tb_customer 
SET password = p.pass
FROM password_new p
WHERE p.cust_cif = tb_customer.cust_cif;
```

But it's easier to write:

```
update tb_customer set password=crypt(cust_cif, gen_salt('md5'));
```

Or, which is not clear in the question, was it your intention to update the password to 'cust_cif', and not to the value of the column `cust_cif` ?